# Using database instead of thousands of small files

Tags: database

At work, I have started working on a program that can potentially generate hundreds of thousands of mostly small files an hour. My predecessors have found out that working with many small files can become very slow, so they have resorted to some (in my opinion) crude methods to alleviate the problem.

So I asked my boss why won't we use a database instead and he gave me his oh-so-famous I-know-better-than-you look and told me *obviously* a database that big won't have a good performance.

My question is, is it really so? It seems to me that a database engine should be able to handle such data much better than the file system. Here are the conditions we have:

- The program mostly writes data. Queries are much less frequent and their performance is not very important.
- Millions of files could be generated every day. Most of these are small (a few kilobytes) but some can be huge.

If you think we should opt with the database solution, what open source database system do you think will work best? (If I decide that a database will certainly work better, I'm going to push for a change whatever the boss says!)

Comment: Your boss can be pretty damn sure that database developer folk have optimized database insertion and retrieval at least as much as your predecessors optimized access to those thousands of small files. Many users swear by MySQL as an open-source DB. And lots of those users run databases of hundreds of thousands of records. Performance is much, much better than you'd get using the bare filesystem, partly because database tables can often be kept in memory (just one of those optimizing techniques, you see). *Obviously!* :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is another one of those "it depends" type questions.

If you are just writing data (write once, read hardly ever) then just use the file system.  Maybe use a hash-directory approach to create lots of sub-directories (things tend to go slowly with many files in a single directory.

If you are writing hundreds of thousands of events for later querying (e.g. find everything with X > 10 and Y < 11) then a database sounds like a great idea.

If you are writing hundreds of thousands of bits of non-relational data (e.g. simple key-value pairs) then it might be worth investigating a [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) approach.

The best approach is probably to prototype all the ideas you can think of, measure and compare!

Comment: Thanks. That's probably what I will be doing. I'm going to pay particular attention to the _NoSQL_ databases because our data mostly resembles to simple key-value pairs (with some annotations which won't often be used in queries). A problem we have with the file system is when we have so many files, sometimes even opening a new file to write to can be slow. Perhaps a document-store or something similar could help.

Comment: For the NoSQL approach, have a look at [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) (and its [GridFS](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS) for the large files). You'd need to test performance for your use-case, but it would at least be a relatively simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

As a minimal impact improvement, I'd split your millions of small files into a heirachy of directories.  So say you were using uuids as your file names, I'd stip out the redundant urn:uuid: at the front, and then make 16 directories based on the first letter, and inside them make 16 subdirectories based on the second letter, and add even more levels if you need it.  That alone will speed up the access quite a bit.  Also, I would remove the directory whenever it became empty, to make sure the directory entry itself doesn't grow larger and larger.